# Displaying Image from SQL Server in Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a couple of images in my SQL Server 2008 table of which the `datatype` is `image`.

In my VS.net 2008 project I have a crystal report which is displaying all the fields from that table, but the image is showing as a blank image.

Any thoughts, How I can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the image before you can show it.

In crystal reports, you can click on the image control and set the value property of the control to the following (replace ImageFieldName with your field name)

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String(Mid(System.Convert.ToBase64String(Fields!ImageFieldName.Value), 105))
```

Comment: Thanks Raj More. When I right click on the control in the Crystal Report Designer how do I format it.

Comment: I am trying this using VS.net 2008. I created a sample report and drag and dropped few columns from the SQL server table. One of them is of image datatype. The one with Image datatype is showing blank though there are images in the database. When I right clicked on blob object I don't get options to place the code as you shown above. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: right click Blob object and go to properties and under `VALUE` put the code

Answer (score 0):

If using the image location data in Table, I use this solution.

Add/Insert Picture box to your Designer, right click on the picture box - Format Object, On the Tab Picture there is Graphic Location option below, use formula and add your image location Field from your database table.

If blank make sure you put the Picture box in the right section (header or detail section)