# Image Access from db in .NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How do I display an image from db on a crystal report in VB.NET?

Comment: Unbelievable, there is no answer at all to any question similar to this one either on SO or using google. I guess CrystalReport just sucks.

Comment: Does this help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170387

Comment: Does this help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764346

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Image_in_Crystal_Reports.aspx).  As long as the Byte array from the database is valid Image data, it should interpret that and display the image.  I know its an old post, but no answers, thought I would help out.