# display image in crystal report using physical path

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

i am using vb.net and access. in which i have one field in which i have saved only the path of that image. Now i want to display that image in crystal report dynamic.so what should i do? i want to fetch the image path in crystal report and display in it.

please try to show me a code so i can identify

reply me soon

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use physical paths with CR directly. Store your image in a datatable or in a binary field of your database and show that.

Here is a code project solution that uses datatables:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Image_in_Crystal_Reports.aspx

It's simple, C# and a little old, but I think you get the trick.

Answer (score 11):

This works in the more recent version of Crystal Reports (i'm using XI R2)

- From the **Insert Tools** toolbar select Insert Picture and insert any old picture in your report.
- Right click on the image and select **Format Graphic**
- On the **Picture** tab select the 'formular button' next to **Graphic Location**
- From the **Formula Workshop** you should be able to select the database column that contains your file path.

When you preview the report it should dynamicly load the images for each record.

**Edit** I've found this [link](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2010/03/15/crystal-reports-dynamic-images/), it maybe useful.